# Broken table header in a Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I need to put a scrollable datatable in a modal bootstrap. The problem is that the header is broken . Only solved if I resize the browser or if I click on the header to reorder. I try to put the same code without the modal and it works perfect, apparently is an incompatibility with the modal and scroll. Without the scroll datatable works well.

I show how it looks when I open the modal:

[image: http://k30.kn3.net/7/2/B/F/2/8/331.png]

I use:

- Bootstrap v3.0.0
- DataTables 1.10.7
- TableTools 2.2.4

My code:

```
$('#rutinasTable').DataTable({
   "sScrollY": "210px",
   "sScrollYInner": "100%",
   "sScrollX": "100%",
   "sScrollXInner": "100%",
   "scrollCollapse": true,
   "pageLength": 50,
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="rutinasTable" class="display table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
   <thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Rutina</th>
      <th>Act. Datos</th>
      <th>Antig. Datos</th>
      <th>Criticidad</th>
      <th>Observaciones</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>SOS</td>
      <td>08/07/2009</td>
      <td>697 hrs</td>
      <td>M-Media</td>
      <td>NIVEL</td>
      <td>Analizar</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

You can see the error in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ennjt3t/7/).

You have to click on the graphic bar to open the modal. To see how it manages the header or try clicking the header to reorder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`destroy`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) option to destroy previously initialized table. Also you need to use `shown.bs.modal` event to initialize the table once it becomes visible.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   chart = $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, options);

   $('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#myInput').focus();

      var dataSet = [   
        ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburg", "5421","2011/04/25", "$320,800"]
      ];

      $('#table').dataTable( {
        "destroy": true,
        //"ajax": "data/objects.txt",
        "sScrollY": "210px",
        "sScrollYInner": "100%",
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "100%",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "url": "/echo/json/",
        "data":dataSet            
      });          
   });
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ennjt3t/9/) for code and demonstration.

> **NOTES**

There were other issues with your code that have been fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!. I tried for hours with my code and not achievement to work. I update the jsFiddle . You can see I'm doing wrong? Thank you  http://jsfiddle.net/8ennjt3t/12/

Comment: I tried removing the tabs and works well. I think that's the problem (Tabs in Modal) . Probably I have to use " shown.bs.tab " but I don't know how

Answer (score 1):

This might work as well:

```
$.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust();
```

Works with Bootstrap 3.5, newest JQuery, Datatables 1.10.9.

```
$('#modal_name_xyz').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust();
});
```

As far as I've understood the mechanics, it adjusts the width after an element has become visible (Modal, Tab etc.). Might even work with a Popover, but I've not tested that. Can cause the tableheader to flicker a second while being resized, though (Modal only, maybe because of the JQuery-Animations?) .

Upside is, that one won't need to initialize a previously initialized table again. Table can be filled, updated and so on using the standard API.